# file_exists in PHP

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can one check to see if a remote file exists using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981954/how-can-one-check-to-see-if-a-remote-file-exists-using-php)
>   [Check if file exists on remote machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235953/check-if-file-exists-on-remote-machine)

I'm having trouble with this code.  I'm trying to search for a file in `$url` below, and the file does exist, but the code is returning `No files located here` instead.  I either have the wrong syntax or I'm not able to search for a file in this manner.

Please help.  Thanks in advance.

```
<?php

function formaction()
{

$url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/" . basename(dirname (dirname (dirname (dirname
(__FILE__))))) . "/process.php"; 

$path = false;

      if (@file_exists($url))
      {
         $path = $url;
      }

else
      {
          echo "No file located here";
      }


return $path;

}

echo formaction();


?>
```

Comment: `file_exists()` doesn't work on URLs

Comment: Perhaps this will be helpful: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php#85246

Comment: HI Pekka, is there a way to call the file the correct way, and then convert that path to a URL like above?  Any guidance would really help.  I only need to convert this into a URL because the other way won't render correctly when I insert it into form action="".  For example, the browser is getting confused when I call it this way...../home2/fortehome/richmindonline/testenvironment...

Comment: Please don't use `@` to suppress errors. It's an incredibly sloppy and lazy practice.

Comment: Yeah, that was copied from another post.  I don't even know what that does...haha.  But I will remove.

Answer (score 1):

Since file_exists() don´t work with url´s:

You can use get_headers() to check its 404 or not go go directly to this snippet:

Taken from PHP Manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php#85246

```
function url_exists($url) {
    // Version 4.x supported
    $handle   = curl_init($url);
    if (false === $handle)
    {
        return false;
    }
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);  // this works
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.15) Gecko/20080623 Firefox/2.0.0.15") ); // request as if Firefox    
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
    $connectable = curl_exec($handle);
    curl_close($handle);   
    return $connectable;
}
```

But in this case, it seens that you dont use to look from an URL.. but, looking for a local script. You should not use URL´s, but the actual absolute or relative path.

Check:

```
echo getcwd() . "\n";
```

Also, check dirname(), you´ll be able to determine the relative / absolute path this way.

Comment: I'm very concerned about this code because only one line is documented as `// this works`.  How do I know the other lines work???