# php checking if a remote rtmp file exists

Tags: php, flash, video, rtmp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check if file exists on remote machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235953/check-if-file-exists-on-remote-machine)

If I have a URI like this

```
rtmp://.../mp4:20122013/..._16x9_1.mp4
```

is there a way in php that can verify and return if that exists or not?  if not in php how can I achieve my purpose?

Comment: Note that RTMP is not supported by php native functions, so you'll have to use curl (or similar). I don't know if it has changed, but in 2010, curl did not support RTMP protocol by default (see http://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2010-07/0020.html).

Comment: Curl wont work. its a different protocol and it doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

Next time do a deeper research on google and stackoverflow.

This article explains how to check if a rtmp stream is up or down using PHP and rtmpdump.

[How to check RTMP source stream is live or not?](http://blog.svnlabs.com/how-to-check-rtmp-source-stream-is-live-or-not/)

if you prefer/need doing this with php native you can use this library

[php-rtmp-client](http://code.google.com/p/php-rtmp-client/)

**UPDATE**

in your case it will need to run :

```
rtmpdump -v -v -r "rtmp://flash.onthefly.nhl.com/ondemand/NHLHighlights//mp4:20122013/02/0118/2_118_nsh_sjs_1213_h_continuous_1600K_16x9_1.mp4" -W "http://nhl.cdn.neulion.net/u/videocenter/flex/images/evp.swf"
```

Check rtmpdump for more info.

Comment: I had tried both of those with no success. this is what happens with rtmp dump http://i50.tinypic.com/30j47zo.png

Comment: and is this link up/working?

Comment: I copy pasted it from here http://i47.tinypic.com/2z67zbr.png

Comment: that didn't work (probably my fault doing something wrong), but I found a alternative to checking rtmp, thanks for your help I appreciate it!

Comment: @DaniloKobold what was your alternative solution? I also need to check if an rtmp stream is up.